# PAYPAL PDT IIS SErVER

Tags: php, iis, paypal

I'm using this as my pdt for my paypal

this does not work when i upload to my IIS server..do i missing something?

```
     $pp_hostname = "www.sandbox.paypal.com"; 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    //set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
    //if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(!$res)
    {
        echo "HTTP ERROR";
    }else
    {
          //my code here
    }
```

Comment: Define *does not work*. We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out . i downloaded the cacert.pem and added it..and it works
!